# How to check table value and export the database using PostgreSQL and Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I need one help. I need to export one database from my `postgreSQL` which is running in my ubuntu server.

first i typed the below command

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
```

it gave me the following result.

[image]

I checked all database using below command

```
\list
```

It gave me the following result.

[image]

I needed to connect the `100salons_production` database and i connected using the following command and checked the tables.

```
\connect 100salons_production
\dt
```

it gave the following result.

[image]

Now i tried to check the table values using this command `select * from areas` but it does not show any result.

[image]

Here I need to check the tables results.and also i need commands to export this database and import it in somewhere else. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: You must append a `;` at the end of the query, i.e. `select * from areas;`.

Comment: Ok,thanks but how to export this database and import into another ubuntu server .Can you help me for the commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to export the database, there is not need to connect to it using the `psql` tool. Instead, you have to use the `pg_dump` tool. You can do that like this:

```
sudo -u postgres pg_dump DATABASE_NAME > dump.sql
```

Then you should transfer `dump.sql` to the other computer and import it there.